# Как убрать адаптивность с адаптивного шаблона?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Был создан сайт с использованием Bootstrap. Теперь хотят, чтобы не было адаптивного дизайна, чтобы и с компьютера и с мобильного устройства сайт выглядел одинаково. Как убрать всю адаптацию?

Пробовал - не помогло:

```
<meta content="min-width=980px, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
```

Comment: >Как убрать всю адаптацию? Читать [документацию.](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Уберите из CSS записи:

   ```
   @media screen and (max-width:600px)
   {
       // всё, что внутри, применяется только для экранов
       // с шириной 600 и меньше пикселей.
   }
   ```
2. Если видите что-то типа:

   ```
   <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4'>
   ```

   Это div, равный 100% ширины для смартфонов (xs), 50% ширины для больших планшетов и нетбуков, 1/3 для больших экранов (в основном desktop).

   Если нужно, чтобы было везде 1/3, ставите:

   ```
   <div class='col-xs-4'>
   <div class='col-xs-6'>
   <div class='col-xs-12'>
   ```

   Почему так?

   Bootstrap-вёрстка делит ширину блока родитель на 12 кусков, вот и получается, что 4 = 1/3 от 12, 6 = 1/2 от 12.

Comment: Для форматирования кода внутри списков следует использовать двойной отступ (8 пробелов). См. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/512/176051

Answer (score 1):

Уберите еще media-запросы из стилей css. Только бэкап не забудьте сделать, на случай если потом попросят адаптивность вернуть :)